# How to find and replace exact match text but not match entire cell contents

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So basically just find and replace but some of my data is so messy

For example I wanna find the word "cat" and replace it with "mr.cat"

but there are some word like "redcat" that will show up in my search too

[image: img]

and If I use the match entire cell contents some word like "the cat" will not show

[image: img2]

Comment: Search for `" cat"`? With a space before the word? And if the left most word is cat then use partial match and search using `"cat"`. Then check if it is the left most word `Ucase(Left(trim(cell.value),3)) ="CAT"`

Comment: It also depends on different kind of words.. For example what would you like to do with words like "this.cat", "that.cat", "Category" etc...

Comment: I reccomend to use the powerful [Regular Expressions (regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops): https://regex101.com/r/BuVKxJ/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another column and include the following formula

```
 =IF(EXACT(A5,"cat"),"mr.cat",SUBSTITUTE(A5," cat"," mr.cat"))
```

[image: example]

Comment: This will not recognize if a cell begins with `"cat"` but is not exactly `"cat"` like in `cat in the house`. You will need a third subtitution criteria: `=IF(EXACT(A5,"cat"),"mr.cat",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5," cat"," mr.cat"),"cat ","mr.cat "))` that covers `"cat "`.